# How do I change an array of characters into an array of integers?

Tags: c

More specifically, how do I change'

```
char tempList[256] = "1 -2 -8 4 5";
```

into something like this:

```
int tempListNum[256] = {1, -2, -8, 4, 5};
```

?

I tried this, but I don't know how to append the array.

```
for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++)
{
    if(TEMPS[j] == 45 && (TEMPS[j+1] >= 48 && TEMPS[j+2] >= 48))
    {
        numToAppend = ((TEMPS[j+1]-'0')*10 + (TEMPS[j+2]-'0')) * -1;
    }
    if(TEMPS[j] == 45 && TEMPS[j+1] >= 48)
    {
        numToAppend = (TEMPS[j+1]-'0') * -1;
    }
    if(TEMPS[j] >= 48)
    {
        numToAppend = TEMPS[j]-'0';
    }
    if(TEMPS[j] >= 48 && TEMPS[j+1] >= 48)
    {
        numToAppend = TEMPS[j]*10 + TEMPS[j+1];
    }
}
```

Comment: `strtok`, `atoi`... get a reference of C's standard library and play with it. Or show what you have tried.

Comment: `strtol()` is the function of choice for this job. Do not use `atoi()` unless you are sure you never need to convert `"0"`, as `0` also is used to indicate failure.

Answer (score 1):

you can use strtok with space as separator and then use atoi standard library function

Comment: When using atoi how to understand mistakes in format? `atoi("0")` and `atoi("x")` both give `0` as result, but no signs to `"x"` as wrong string value. I prefer sscanf because its return.

Answer (score 0):

For example, with while loop and functions sscanf and strtok from `strings.h`.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main (void)
{
    char tempList[256] = "1 -2 -8 4 5";
    int tempListNum[256] = {0};
    int cnt = 0;
    int tmp = 0;
    char * str = strtok (tempList," ");
    while(str != NULL)
    {
        if(sscanf(str, "%d", &tmp))
        {
            tempListNum[cnt] = tmp;
            cnt++;
        }
        // read next number
        str = strtok (NULL," ");
    }
    // test output
    for(tmp = 0; tmp < cnt; tmp++)
    {
        printf("%d ", tempListNum[tmp]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Tested in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: I prefer to understand why my answer is useless... can you provide some feedback?

Comment: I understand.... i just have forgotten to put data in tempListNum (it was just printing numbers with printf) :-)   Now, my example is more completed

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that goes through `tempList` `char` by `char`:

- While it encounters only numbers, it should turn them into an `int`. If there are more than 1 digit, it should multiply the first digit with `10` and add then add it to the `int`, etc.
- When it encounters a space, it should add the newly created `int` to `tempListNum` and skip the space.
- When it encounters a minus sign, it should multiply the currently created `int` with `-1`.
- Repeat these steps until end of list.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
unsigned char index1 = 0,index2 =0;
int PrevValue = 0;
for(;index1 <= 255;index1 ++)
{
      if(tempList[index1] != ' ') //space
      {
         tempListNum[index2] = PrevValue*10 + (tempList[index1]-0x30);
         PrevValue = tempListNum[index2] ;

      }
      else
      {  
           PrevValue  = 0;
           index2++;
      }

}
```

You can add further optimizations and other validations.

Answer (score 0):

use this: it works on me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    char tempList[256] = "1 -2 -82 43 5";
    char tempNumber[10];
    int tempNumberCounter = 0;
    int i, j,counter=0, isNegative = 1;
    int numTempList[256] = {0};

    for(i=0; tempList[i] != '\0'; i++) {

        if(tempList[i-1] == '-') {
            isNegative = -1;
        }

        if(isdigit(tempList[i])) {
            tempNumber[tempNumberCounter] = tempList[i];
            tempNumberCounter++;
        }

        if(tempList[i] == ' ' || tempList[i+1] == '\0') {
            tempNumber[tempNumberCounter] = '\0';

            for(j=0; j<strlen(tempNumber); j++) {
                numTempList[counter] += (tempNumber[j] - '0') * pow(10, strlen(tempNumber)-j-1);
            }           

            numTempList[counter] *= isNegative;
            counter++;
            tempNumberCounter = 0;
            *tempNumber = 0;
            isNegative = 1;
        }
        
    }

    for(i=0; numTempList[i] != 0; i++) {
        printf("%d ", numTempList[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`numTempList` is the converted array from `tempList`. this is just a sample implementation of char to int array, you can refactor this into functions so that you can reuse this functionality..

## Modified:

Now it can also read multiple digits

Comment: If the number is more than a digit long, should I use isdigit(tempList[i]) && isdigit(tempList[i+1])?

Comment: @Gensoukyou1337, youre right, it only works for single digits like your example.. I'll edit my answer later for multiple digits...

Comment: @Gensoukyou1337 you should not use `tempList[i+1]` since there is no telling if its one digit long or more than that.. you should create a temporary array that will hold the values of digits while it is iterating..

Comment: I used "if(isdigit(tempList[i+3]))" inside "if(isdigit(tempList[i+2]))" inside "if(isdigit(tempList[i+1]))" inside "if(isdigit(tempList[i+3]))". The problem did tell me the number of digits - the elements range from -273 to 5526.

Comment: @Gensoukyou1337, the limitation of your implementation is that it cannot check the digit `isdigit(tempList[i+4...n])` since it only ends in 3... and another, if your checking is far over the size of the array, it will cause an error..
I modified my sample code and it works on multiple digits now..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
char tempList[256] = "1 -2 -8 4 5";
int tempListNum[256]

int i=0,k=0;
while(i<256)
{
  int num=0;
  for(int j=0;tempList[j]!=' ';j++)
  {
    int neg=0,counter=0; //Not worked in C for a long time and I am not sure if it supports Bools
    if(a[j]=='-')
     neg=1;
    else
     num=num*10+int(tempList[j])-int('0');
    counter++;
 }
  if(neg==1)
   num=-num;
  tempListNum[k]=num;
  k++; i+=counter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't terribly difficult. I'd recommend a custom `strtoi` function instead of `atoi` since `atoi` allows for little error handling. For example, `atoi("1.3")` would return 1 with no other way to get other information like the fact that ".3" makes it not an integer. Moreover, the value 1 is obviously within the range of the `int` type, so even `errno` may not be of help.

That is why I write and use `strtoi` below, which uses the C library's `strtol` function and has the same behaviors. If you need help understanding what `strtoi` does, look up documentation for `strtol` since they're pretty much the same except for the range of valid values (between `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX`, both inclusive, instead of between `LONG_MIN` and `LONG_MAX`, both inclusive).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //strtol
#include <string.h> //strtok
#include <limits.h> //INT_MIN, INT_MAX
#include <errno.h> //errno, ERANGE

int
strtoi (const char *s, char **rem, int base)
{
  long n;
  int esave = errno;

  errno = 0;
  n = strtol (s, rem, base);
  if (n < INT_MIN || n > INT_MAX)
    errno = ERANGE;

  if (errno)
    {
      if (n == LONG_MAX)
        return INT_MAX;
      return INT_MIN;
    }

  errno = esave;
  return (int) n;
}

int
main (void)
{
  char tempList[256] = "1 -2 -8 4 5";
  int tempListNum[128] = {0};
  int i, n;
  char *listPtr;
  char *listPtr2;

  listPtr = strtok (tempList, " ");
  for (i = 0;
       listPtr != NULL && (size_t) i < sizeof tempListNum / sizeof tempListNum[0];
       ++i)
    {
      errno = 0;
      n = strtoi (listPtr, &listPtr2, 10);

      if (*listPtr2)
        {
          fprintf (stderr, "error: value `%s' is not an integer ... ignoring value\n", listPtr);
          --i;
        }

      // value out of range or some other implementation-defined error
      else if (errno)
        {
          perror (listPtr);
        }

      listPtr = strtok (NULL, " ");
    }

  // n is now the number of items in the array
  n = i;

  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    printf ("%d\n", tempListNum[i]);
}
```

You could obviously avoid `strtok` and just use `strtoi` by itself. That might actually be a cleaner solution!

Answer (score 0):

Is this a homework assignment, or maybe a interview question?

I haven't tested this, but you could do something like this:

```
#define enum _error {
   success = 0,
   parse_error,
   out_of_memory,
   invalid_arg,
   insuficient_buffer
} error;

error parse_int(
   char **pp,
   int *val)
{
   error e = success;
   char neg = 0;

   if (!pp || !*pp || !val) {
      e = invalid_arg;
      goto exit;
   }

   *val = 0;

   while (**pp) {
      if (**pp == '-') {
         if (val) {
            e = parse_error;
            goto exit;
         }

         neg = 1;
      }
      else if (**pp >= '0' **pp <= '9') {
          *val *= 10;
          *val += **pp - '0';
      }
      else {
         break;
      }

      ++*pp; 
   }

   if (neg) {
      *val *= -1;
   }

exit:

   return e;
}

error parse_array_of_ints(
   char *p,
   unsigned int parsed_ints_size,
   int **parsed_ints)
{
   error e = success;
   unsigned int cur = 0;

   if (!p || !parsed_ints) {
      e = invalid_arg;
      goto exit;
   }

   for (;;) {
      while (*p && *p != '-' && *p < '0' && *p > '9') {
         p++;
      }

      if (!*p) {
         break;
      }

      if (cur = parsed_ints_size) {
         e = insuficient_buffer;
         goto exit;
      }

      e = parse_int(&p, parsed_ints+cur);

      if (e != success) {
         goto exit;
      }

      cur++;
   }

exit:

   return e;
}
```

Comment: It's a coding exercise, actually.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this short example:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
  char tempList[256] = "1 -2 -8 4 5";
  int tempListNum[256] = {0};
  int numCnt = 0;
  char * pEnd = tempList;
  int number = 0;
  while( strlen(pEnd) > 0)
  {
    tempListNum[numCnt] = strtol (pEnd,&pEnd,0);
    numCnt++;
  }
  for(number = 0; number < numCnt; number++)
  {
      printf("%d ", tempListNum[number]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```